# How to deal with 'Is it correct' questions?

Tags: discussion, comments

Today I encountered [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11661/3335) which asks whether the punctuation of a given sentence is correct.
It is correct, however, I have only added a comment since I consider a statement such as "It is correct" to be too short for an answer.

**Question**: how to deal with questions whose answer are either 'yes' or 'no'?

I can imagine

- writing a comment
- or writing an answer and elaborating on the topic

However, the latter can sometimes really be an overkill, for example when the OP actually knows the grammar rules, but he just wants to get confirmed by others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, good question.

I also often feel it's not worth posting a full answer to a question whose answer is, um, that simple.

And though, "writing an answer and elaborating on the topic" is the right choice.

There are several reasons:

- The question itself is actually a little poor if asking for "Correct? – Yes/No". The question actually should ask for "Why?", too. At the very least. So, why don't go on and elaborate on this "Why?" part. See [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11673/1224).
  Furthermore, if it's not clear what the actual problem is, we should ask for clarifications (in comments) and/or should vote for close.
- We'd like to provide sort of knowledge base for future visitors, too. To prevent duplicate questions which basically ask for the same issue, having a great answer to such a question would be awesome. We can always refer to this answer whenever this topic appears again.
  It's worth to mention that we should also edit the question's title so that it does not ask for "Correct? – Yes/No" any more; instead, it should reflect the actual problem.
- We're still in beta. Our biggest problem is still the low number of questions per day, but with an increasing number of questions, our answer ratio is decreasing. So, if you see you can contribute and provide an answer, then do that. Use comments for clarification or off-topic hints or such.