# Questions of the type "Check for correctness": when is it too simple?

Tags: discussion, community-moderation

We recently(?) see quite a few questions of the type "Which is correct" or "Is this correct" which can often be answered by rather simple "X is correct" - and possibly an explanation. However sometimes it seems rather short.

This was [brought up ages ago already on meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-to-deal-with-is-it-correct-questions), but not conclusively. In principle these kind of questions are on-topic (as it's a question about the language itself), however where do we draw the border to "this is too simple" or "you can look this up"?

The most recent question of this type is [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76665/gebaut-werden-w%C3%BCrde) which already gathered 3 close votes as of the time of writing - and in that case I don't really see why it should be closed. So how do we deal with this on which basis?

Answer (score 1):

If a technically correct answer to a question would be "Yes, it is correct" it will often be wise to ask for clarification in a comment on the question: What are the specific problems they face, why would they assume their solution is correct or incorrect, why are they insecure about it? The answer to this will be the underlying question and answering this will usually be more helpful than a technically correct "Yes, correct" or "No, this is wrong".